# How to push next class without class name instead of using NSString in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have many class like Page1 , Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5 ..............

I want to write one method to go to the next class and it will call Page1,2,3 according to my need.

Here is my code what I am doing:

```
 for (int j = 0; j<5; j++) {

    NSString *str_varForPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j];

    if ([txt_Chapter.text isEqualToString:str_Chapter] && [txt_Page.text isEqualToString:str_varForPage]) {

        NSString *Str_Page = @"Page";
        NSString *Str_NextPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", Str_Page , str_varForPage];
        NSLog(@"Str_NextPage is: %@",Str_NextPage);


        Str_NextPage *nextclass= [[Str_NextPage alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];       // error  Crash  , I want to call Page0 to Page4 classes here according to my need.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextclass animated:YES];
    }
```

Any idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Comment: post error message here.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector alloc

Comment: change either string name(Str_NextPage) or classname.

Comment: use of undeclared identifier 'nextclass'

Comment: My class names are Page0, Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4....

Comment: use @Chandu's answer it will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initiate a object of any class like this.

```
NSString *nextPage = @"Page1";
Page1 *nextclassInstance = [[[NSClassFromString(nextPage) alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextclassInstance animated:YES];
```

Comment: I cant understand Sir. Please tell me how can I use this line [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextclass animated:YES];

Comment: @Tina , do this =>  id object =  [[NSClassFromString(Str_NextPage) alloc] init];         [self.navigationController pushViewController:object animated:YES];

Comment: Wow its great... Working Fine Sir. Mr. Chandu,Reformer,Sunny: Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 1):

use like below code snippet:

```
Class someClassMetaClass = NSClassFromString(Str_Page);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController *)someClassMetaClass animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

//if you want to switch specific viewController With Storyboard, You can use like this:-

```
LargeImageView *largeImageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LargeImageView"];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:largeImageViewController animated:YES];
```

//if you want to switch specific viewController With out using storyboard, You can use like this:-

```
MasterViewController *masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:masterVC animated:YES];
```

//if you want to switch specific class, You can use like this:-

```
NSString *movePage = @"PageName";
Page0 *nxtPage = [[[NSClassFromString(movePage) alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController:nxtPage animated:YES];
```